# laplace transform of moving average

Tags: laplace-transform

I am working on a dc-dc converter course where we are given the below laplace transform of a moving average.

[image]

I do not fully understand what substituion(s) or methods are used to otbain the final G_av(s) equation shown on the right hand-side. Please can someone provide some help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I editted it. Thank you for the feedback